iwlwifi with 8265-36 chipset, range massively decreased with newer kernel
I recently got me a refurbished HP Elitebook x260 1030 G3 which comes with a 8265-36 intel wireless chipset. Installation of Ubuntu 22.04 went fine and it recognised my wireless network fine. Likewise first use was also OK. However after first apt upgrade and reboot, we noticed the wireless is still working but not seeing any wifi networks, (the router is one floor away) which works fine for every other device.
I did some significant troubleshooting the past few hours and I've tracked it down to the kernel version. Currently the laptop is using the latest 6.5.0-26-generic kernel.
The steps I've tried during troubleshooting:

Reboot from the liveCD. The wifi network is seen as normal in the liveCD 5.19.0-32-generic kernel. The firmware on the liveCD is the same as the firmware on the installed version.
Downgrade the iwlwifi firmware to the previous version available in linux-firmware. No change. Restored to latest firmware
Downgraded to various other kernels, along with their iwlwifi module (e.g. linux-modules-iwlwifi-6.2.0-25-generic). Most of them didn't even recognise the wifi device.
Eventually downgraded to linux kernel 5.19.0-50-generic which finally seems to work as normal (i.e. with proper wifi range)
The system also still includes the liveCD 5.19.0-32 kernel, but that one doesn't work. I assume because the linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.19.0-32-generic package does not exist in the ubuntu repositories to be installed. Not sure.

So currently, only 5.19.0-50-generic along with linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.19.0-25-generic works as expected. All the other kernel versions either don't recognise the wireless card, or have massively reduced range (I have to be standing almost next to the router).
I would have just stayed on 5.19.0-50 but unfortunately that one has a buggy touchpad making it borderline unusable.
Any suggestions on how I can make the wifi work correctly on the latest kernel?
